# css grids change layout depending on page

Tags: css

so i have my main page that have a menu , sidebar and main window. I have a redirect to another page. On this page i would like the sidebar to go away.

Is this possible using CSS grids without having 2 CSS files?

so for example this would be the grids for index.html

```
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'menu menu menu menu'
  'mainWindow mainWindow mainWindow chat'
  'footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 0.6em;
  column-gap: 1.2em;
}
```

on redirect to myOtherPage.html

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'menu menu menu menu '
  'mainWindow mainWindow mainWindow mainWindow '
  'footer footer footer footer';
   grid-gap: 0.6em;
   column-gap: 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure your `CSS` as such. The first block has the styles all `.grid-container`s share. The next is unique to whatever `other-page` should be.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'menu menu menu menu'
  'mainWindow mainWindow mainWindow chat'
  'footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 0.6em;
  column-gap: 1.2em;
}

.grid-container.other-page {
  grid-template-areas:
  'menu menu menu menu '
  'mainWindow mainWindow mainWindow mainWindow '
  'footer footer footer footer';
}
```

**index**

```html
<div class="grid-container">...</div>
```

**other page**

```html
<div class="grid-container other-page">...</div>
```